# in-app purchase methods(mkstorekit? )

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an app at the appstore , and i would like to add it in-app purchase, a basic one ,in order to purchase more levels .

I know that the `apple sdk` is very hard to implement,
I know the `mkstorekit` is an easy one, but i cant find a guide from scratch to use it .

Whats the best way to do so, any other method ?any good tutorial ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize MKStoreKit. A sample initializiation code that you can add to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is below In Objective-C

```
[[MKStoreKit sharedKit] startProductRequest];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMKStoreKitProductsAvailableNotification
                                                    object:nil
                                                     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

    NSLog(@"Products available: %@", [[MKStoreKit sharedKit] availableProducts]);
  }];


  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMKStoreKitProductPurchasedNotification
                                                    object:nil
                                                     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                  NSLog(@"Purchased/Subscribed to product with id: %@", [note object]);
                                                }];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMKStoreKitRestoredPurchasesNotification
                                                    object:nil
                                                     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                  NSLog(@"Restored Purchases");
                                                }];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMKStoreKitRestoringPurchasesFailedNotification
                                                    object:nil
                                                     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                  NSLog(@"Failed restoring purchases with error: %@", [note object]);
                                                }];
```

You can check if a product was previously purchased using -isProductPurchased as shown below.

```
if([MKStoreManager isProductPurchased:productIdentifier]) {
//unlock it
}
```

You can check for a product's expiry date using -expiryDateForProduct as shown below.

```
if([MKStoreManager expiryDateForProduct:productIdentifier]) {
//unlock it
}
```

To purchase a feature or to subscribe to a auto-renewing subscription, just call

```
[[MKStoreKit sharedKit] initiatePaymentRequestForProductWithIdentifier:productIdentifier];
```

You can also find tutorials of mkstorekit [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/introducing-mkstorekit-%E2%80%93-version-3/) and [here.](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)